# HERE map controls design

Tags: javascript, css, maps, here-api

I'm using HERE maps API for javascript, but I want to change the design of the map controls like this:

I attached an example

[HERE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp4Iw.png)

Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely Yes, I'm not sure what library and platform you are using, but here are some options:

1. If you are using the "HERE Maps API for Javascript", please refer to https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/dev_guide/topics/map-controls-ui.html, and searching the keywords "Managing the Position of UI Controls", the demo codes like below:

```html
var mapSettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
var zoom = ui.getControl('zoom');
var scalebar = ui.getControl('scalebar');

mapSettings.setAlignment('top-left');
zoom.setAlignment('top-left');
scalebar.setAlignment('top-left');
```

If you are developing with its mobile SDKs (https://developer.here.com/products/here-sdk), it has the document of the SDK, which has a similar description as above, please check it out.

2. Any other open source libraries, such as OpenLayers, Leaflets etc. the best way is modifying its CSS file to get the position what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am looking for something like the image that I attached in the question Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: Sorry I didn't tried with "Here Maps API", but that's easy for OpenLayers and Leaflets. I don't think there is any difference with "Here Maps". there isn't any SDK has these controls, the only way is creating  these "image buttons" by yourself, but call the corresponding API to switch the "map's base layer" or "zoom in/out".